# Why does the function "NMaximize" produce a new result while the condition changes from the subset of the set A to A?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
In[1]:= DIU2[a1_, c1_] = 
 Simplify[1/
   8 (Sqrt[1 - a1^2 - 
       c1^2] (14 Sqrt[1 - a1^2 - c1^2] + 
        2 Sqrt[1 - a1^2 - c1^2] Cos[2 \[Theta]] + 
        Sqrt[2] (a1 + c1) Sin[2 \[Theta]]) + 
     a1 (9 a1 + 5 c1 - (a1 + c1) Cos[2 \[Theta]] + 
        Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - a1^2 - c1^2] Sin[2 \[Theta]]) + 
     c1 (5 a1 + 9 c1 - (a1 + c1) Cos[2 \[Theta]] + 
        Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - a1^2 - c1^2] Sin[2 \[Theta]]))]

Out[1]= 1/8 (14 - 5 a1^2 + 10 a1 c1 - 
   5 c1^2 - (-2 + 3 a1^2 + 2 a1 c1 + 3 c1^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]] + 
   2 Sqrt[2] (a1 + c1) Sqrt[1 - a1^2 - c1^2] Sin[2 \[Theta]])

In[14]:= NMaximize[{Simplify[DIU2[a1, c1] /. {\[Theta] -> 1.2}], 
  0 <= a1 <= 1 && 0 <= c1 <= 1 && a1^2 + c1^2 <= 1}, {a1, c1}]

\:6B63\:5728\:8BA1\:7B97In[14]:= NMaximize::nrnum: The function value -1.75565-0.0964303 I is not a real number at {a1,c1} = {0.426364,0.95088}.

Out[14]= {1.92067, {a1 -> 0.437452, c1 -> 0.70154}}

In[13]:= NMaximize[{Simplify[DIU2[a1, c1] /. {\[Theta] -> 1.2}], 
  0 <= a1 <= 1/Sqrt[2] && 0 <= c1 <= 1/Sqrt[2] && 
   a1^2 + c1^2 <= 1}, {a1, c1}]

Out[13]= {2., {a1 -> 0.659051, c1 -> 0.659051}}
```

There are two kinds of boundary conditions, A and B, ant it satisfies A is contained in B. However，the maximum value with the condition A is bigger than B?

Comment: The warning message in the first case indicates that the search **terminated** when the constraints were violated and the result is the maximum found at that point in the search. In the second case, there is no warning and the search terminated at the maximum. When you get a warning try to figured out what it may imply.

Comment: There are workarounds `NMaximize[{Simplify[DIU2[a1, c1] /. {\[Theta] -> 1.2}], 
  0 <= a1 <= 1 && 0 <= c1 <= 1 && a1^2 + c1^2 <= 1}, {a1, c1}, 
 Method -> "RandomSearch"]` and `NMaximize[{Simplify[DIU2[a1, c1] /. {\[Theta] -> 1.2}], 
  0 <= a1 <= 1 && 0 <= c1 <= 1 && a1^2 + c1^2 <= 1}, {a1, c1}, 
 Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 0}]`.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks a lot! Why will it work by adding the order "Method -> RandomSearch"  or "Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 0}"?

Comment: @HengjiLi: Don't know it.

Comment: `NMaximize` is not guaranteed to find a maximum. It has several methods available each of which has a certain robustness and each which will sometimes fail on this or that problem. I'm not surprised that changing conditions or methods sometimes result in different results. Numerical global optimization can be hard to solve.

Answer (score 1):

NMaximize gets confused when coming into an area with complex function values.

Since your conditions allow only variable-values where the function is real, you can set a "Re" before the function.

```
  NMaximize[{Re[DIU2[a1, a1] /. {\[Theta] -> 1.2}], 
     0 <= a1 <= 1 && 0 <= c1 <= 1 && a1 == c1 && 2 a1^2 <= 1}, 
     {a1, c1}]

(*   {2., {a1 -> 0.659051, c1 -> 0.659051}}   *)
```

Comment: The question arises: why does `NMaximize[{Simplify[DIU2[a1, c1] /. {\[Theta] -> 1.2}],    0 <= a1 <= 1 && 0 <= c1 <= 1 && a1^2 + c1^2 <= 1}, {a1, c1},   Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 0}]` not need  `Re`?

Comment: A look into the tutorial  "tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical" says, "The j\[Null]^th new point is generated by picking three random points, Subscript[x, u], Subscript[x, v] and Subscript[x, w], from the old population, and forming Subscript[x, s]=Subscript[x, w]+s(Subscript[x, u]-Subscript[x, v]), where s is a real scaling factor ..."   Here maximum is close to the imaginary area, where it gets confused. ScalingFactor of 10^-3 also does the job.

Comment: Thank you. Frankly speaking, I don't understand your explanation "Here maximum is close to the imaginary area, where it gets confused". How about ` Method -> "RandomSearch"`?

Comment: The algorithm of "DifferentialEvolution" generates  new searching points a little bit away from previous tested points. This distance is determined by "ScalingFactor".  It seems this intermediate calculation points are not forced to lie within the area determined by conditions. You get an error when their function values are complex. Since here maximum is close to the area where you get imaginary function values, small "ScalingFactor" helps you not to get intermediate imaginary points, when started from real area.  It seem only finally found maximum points are testes for conditions.